# Links on header links

Tags: magento2.4

i been trying to add some links as shown in the picture...my intention is to add a phtml template block so i can easily modify in the future, how can i do this?

i am using magento 2.4.4, i have tried many things, one of them is using a simple block class that works in the container referenceContainer name="main...but does not work on referenceBlock name="top.links

Here is the block

block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="mylinks" template="Magento_Theme::html/mylinks.phtml

[image: my goal]

Answer (score 0):

In your custom module you can do this using the following code:

app\code\vendor\ModuleName\view\frontend\layout

In here add a file called **default.xml** and place the following code:

```
<referenceBlock name="header.links">
<block class="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\CustomLink" name="custom-header-link">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Header Link</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

in app\code\vendor\ModuleName\Block place the following file:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Block;

class CustomLink extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link
{
    public function getHref()
    {
        //place your link here
        return 'https://www.google.com/';
    }

    public function getTarget()
    {
        return '_blank';
    }
}
```

You will need to compile your code and clean cache.

If this solved your issue please upvote and mark as answered.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my question with a little tweak...